# TFS unit tests passing on developer machine but failing on build machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs, tdd, build-automation

I have some unit tests that are passing on developer machine but failing on TFS build machine. These tests are failing for different reasons. I have very limited access to build machine. But I could look into the drop folder and see what DLL files were deployed etc.

Also I see that pdb files were deployed on the build machine.

**Is there any way to debug and step through the code on why its only failing on build machine?**

Comment: what does the test results file .trx show? it should have some info that can help?

Comment: But more diagnostic code in place and check the logs. The test output (test results folder in solution directory) should give you a stack trace. Also, if your tests are not providing useful errors then you either have a critical failure or your tests/code are not well written (or both).

Comment: You've probably been downvoted because this isn't a question. Look into remote debugging.

Comment: please take out the down vote. this is a good legit quetsion.

Comment: I wouldnt go for remote debugging cause its a bit of a hassle. Unit test should run on any pc which you already know. So i'd tweak nunit / mstest output and go through the failing tests 1 by 1. They prolly fail on something obvious. Maybe you could post 1 of the tests? Ps gave you a +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to debug and step through the code on why its only
>   failing on build machine?

Yes you can attach to the process on the build machine...  But you would have to be logged into the Build machine and have an instance of VS running on the server and have Admin rights to attach to the thread...

You could also do it if the admins were willing to open up the server to remote debugging.  But since that opens up more of a security risk than just giving you access to the server it is unlikely that this option is viable either.

So for you no.  You will need to look at what the failures are and figure out what would cause that to happen.  Then you can try to fix that.

Comment: To make this easy consider adding the following code to your unit test:  System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();  Then RDP into the server and it will prompt you to debug!  This is a lot easier than trying to setup remote debugging or time it just right to attach to QAgent

Comment: @ProVega - I do not know for sure that will work, but assuming it does I would expand that into an answer and include a small walk through of how it works.  I would include what rights you would need on the server.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a batch file to run msbuild, then you can view the progress of the whole process in the console. Here is some starter code for ya:

```
ECHO Starting Build 
:: Change to MSBuild Directory
CD C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
PAUSE
:: READY TO RUN?
ECHO READY TO RUN...
MSBuild.exe "C:\Users\PATH TO YOUR PROJECT HERE\.csproj" /t:MsDeployPublish /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://DOMAINHERE.com:8172/msdeploy.axd;DeployIisAppPath="IIS SITE NAME HERE";username=USERNAME;password=PASSWORD;AllowUntrustedCertificate=True;Configuration=Release
:: Outputs tons of network information into the command prompt
ECHO All done.
PAUSE
```

Wherever I have caps replace with your settings.... The save the .bat file, double click and you can trace everything in the console.

Comment: The question was about failing unit tests and not building the solution. An example of MSTEST.exe instead of MSBUILD.EXE would have been more acceptable